# Can the terms in the microscopic model with nonzero conformal spin generate some new term(s) under RG (renormalization group) flow?

Tags: renormalization, conformal-field-theory, critical-phenomena, strong-correlated, bosonization

As in the book *Bosonization and Strongly Correlated Systems* at page 66, it says that

"We see that the original perturbation with **nonzero conformal spin** generates the perturbation with **zero conformal spin**".

There in fact it considers the effect interchain of  hopping term between two spinless fermionic chain . The original perturbation means the interchain hopping term in bosonization language as (or see the formula (8.9) at page 64 in the book I mentioned above):
$$ V = g \int dz d\bar z\, \cos(\beta \Phi) \cos(\bar\beta \Theta)$$
And the perturbation generated by this term under the RG procedure are (see page 66, (8.18))
\begin{align*}
  V_1 &= g_1 \cos(2\beta\Phi) & (\beta < \bar \beta)\\
  V_2 &= g_2 \cos(2\bar\beta\Theta) & (\beta > \bar \beta)
\end{align*}

My question is that how to understand this statement? In general, is it right for the below case:

1. in the framework of bosoniztion, can a perturbation with nonzero spin always gives rise to new term with zero conformal spin? (Further can a perturbation term with zero conformal spin give rise to new perturbation term?)
2. for a generic action (no matter in 1,2,3 spacial dimension and also no matter boson or fermion)including perturbation terms with nonzero conformal spin, can such terms generate some new perturbation terms under the RG procedure?

Last question is that:

For a action with some perturbation terms, if some symmetry are imposed, under the RG procedure, what terms would be generated by higher order perturbation?

Thanks for anything you guys think helpful for me to understand these.